# How to use Thymeleaf in a referenced JavaScript-File instead of between <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

This is how we access `[[${message}]]` in JavaScript:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

    var message = [[${message}]];
    console.log(message);

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Since I don't want to use inline JavaScript, I have referenced a JavaScript file as followed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

How can I access `[[${message}]]` in a my **external JavaScript file**, app.js?

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf 3 introduced [new template modes](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html#template-modes), one of which is javascript.  So in addition to your `TemplateResolver` that returns html, you need to configure a new `TemplateResolver` that returns javascript resources instead. Then you'd create a controller as normal except it would be serving your javascript:

```
@Controller
public class JavascriptController {

  @RequestMapping("/js/app.js")
  public String greeting(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Here is a message.");
    return "/where/your/js/is/app.js";
  }
}
```

It would use the model as normal to pass variables to your external javascript.

Comment: normaly you return a HTML file. If I return a js-File, how will the html-file ever load?

Comment: I did this: `<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/appjs}"></script>` like in Thymeleaf 3 docs, but it seems that `[[${message}]]` still not beeing reconized

Comment: The point is, you are returning both.  An html file is no different from a js file from the servers point of view.  Did you create the new TemplateResolver and try and access the javascript file directly?